# Unable To get Activity name from adb command Android 10

Tags: android, shell, adb, appium-android

I'm trying to get activity name for current focused app on the device by running this command:

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocusApp|mFocusedApp'"
```

It works on older phone with Android 6.0 but on Pixel XL running Android 10 its returns nothing.

If I run only `dumpsys window windows` it returns bunch of unfiltered info which is not very efficient for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
adb shell dumpsys activity a . | grep -E 'mResumedActivity' | cut -d ' ' -f 8
```

Answer (score 1):

John answer is great but u can use:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep mActivityRecord
```

in that case u get list of all current run app in memory
if u kill all app and run the one u want u get 2 records

```
# launcher 
mActivityRecord=ActivityRecord{99197dc u0 com.sec.android.app.launcher/.activities.LauncherActivity t3161}
# active app
mActivityRecord=ActivityRecord{6dec4d5 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.monet.MonetActivity t3711}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep "mFocused"
```

It worked on android 10 & 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep "mCur"
```

That you can find the first window you're interacting, maybe is an activity